# angular Controller in ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

i have this files under my project and i'm encountring some trouble loading them with ajax and applying angular , here is the plunk : 
http://plnkr.co/MxXzlenAuGcDy8iljKYX

the problem is that the content of **sidebar.html** get loaded and the controller gets executed correctly but for **products.html** the content only gets loaded and the controller doesn't get executed. 
i am using this under chrome and i don't get any errors in my localhost console

Comment: This all seems very convoluted is there a reason for the manual bootstrap?  Check out ng-include which will load the sidebar.html async for you and ngRoute (need to include angular-route.js to use this) for handling the navigation for a single view, if you need nested views check out ui-router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a modified version of your plnkr to show how I would approach this in general with Angular and dropped out jQuery since it wasn't necessary here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QgPUk1JMP1vaWtwgXGbw

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.14"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular-route.js" data-semver="1.2.14"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="category.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="products.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-include="'sidebar.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("myApp" , ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when("/products/:prodId",{templateUrl:"products.html"})
    .when("/products",{templateUrl:"products.html"})
    .when("/", {templateUrl:"home.html"})
    .otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
  })
```

Comment: what i've putted in plnkr is just a mini version of my project , when i try to apply this, the app crashes like there is an infinite loop somewhere , when i go to "#/" but with "#/products" it works correctly

Comment: Check through your products.html and categories.html files and make sure they aren't also loading the scripts, if you can show the issue in a plunker I can help debug further.

Comment: thanks a lot i had a problem in home.html where there was another ng-view i forgot it there by mistake